# Rust serde returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

Tags: rust

```
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct User<'a> {
  name: &'a str,
}

fn main() {
  let out = parse();
  println!("{:?}", out);
}

fn parse<'a>() -> Vec<User<'a>> {
  let args: Vec<String> = std::env::args().collect();
  let json = args[0].to_owned();
  let out = serde_json::from_str::<Vec<User>>(&json);
  let out = out.unwrap();
  return out;
}
```

And then, I get error,

```
  --> src/main.rs:18:10
   |
16 |   let out = serde_json::from_str::<Vec<User>>(&json);
   |                                               ----- `json` is borrowed here
17 |   let out = out.unwrap();
18 |   return out;
   |          ^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

How do I solve this? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, usually it's best to use `String` instead of `&str`. Like this:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct User {
    name: String,
}
```

`String` is an *owned* type, so it can live "on its own" so to speak. Whereas `&str` is just a *reference* (a pointer) to a piece of data.

What you are trying to do in your `parse()` function is return a value, containing references to `json` - a value that will get dropped automatically as the function execution is over. Imagine, for example, what would `out` contain at this point:

```
println!("{:?}", out);
```

It would contain references to a value that has already been dropped.